# How Can I Track The Code Version of My Application Within Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics.js

Looking for insight into how I can programmatically track my code version (aka release version 1.0,1.1,1.2 etc) within google analytics. Currently I manually mark annotations but since annotations can't be added via API perhaps there is another mechanism? Looking for insight into how others have done this. The business case would be allowings other to see how different releases affects traffic/segments.

Reposted From Google Analytics Forum:

Hi All, Just wondering how others have tracked application versions programatically. Currently every time we release code we go into google analytics (manually) and create an annotation with the release number. This allows our GA users to see when we released and cross-reference the release to any potential changes in traffic/conversion/etc. There is currently no way to programmatically create that annotation (https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=53) however how do others track this. Perhaps there is a recommended way or every time you send a GA event you include the application release number, which we have hidden in the HTML of the site.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/analytics/COIXYUCgAXg/nfVctltmDj8J

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom dimension and push the release version into it.Later you can use the custom dimension to segment the user based on ur requirements

Comment: Yea I thought about that but then I have to refactor all my reports. Also it doesn't seem like the right way to do this.